# Implicitly differentiate cone volume

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I think I have the derivative with respect to $ h $ right for the equation $V = \frac {1}{3} r^2h $. I got $$\frac {dV}{dh} = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 + \frac {2}{3}\pi rh \frac {dr}{dh} $$.

Is that correct?   Thanks!

Comment: If $v = (\pi/3) r^{2} h$ then your expression $\partial_{h} v = (\pi r/3)( r + 2 h \partial_{h} r)$  is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. Have confidence, you are on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your support!